# Powershellでダブルクォーテションで囲まれた文字列を置換したい

Tags: powershell

csvファイルをタブ区切りでsqlserverにbulkinsertしたいのですが、文字列にダブルクォーテーションで囲まれたカラムが混在しています。
さらにそのダブルクォーテーション付きのカラムにはカンマもあります。
普通であればダブルクォーテーションを削除してカンマをタブに変換すればいいのですが上記がネックとなります。
そのため前処理として、

1. カンマを別の値（被らなければなんでもよい）に置換
2. ダブルクォーテションンを削除
3. カンマをタブに変換

をしたいです。

文字列
    1,12345,"aaa,bbb",56789,"aaa",34567

例えば、`"aaa,bbb"`のカンマだけを`x`に置換して`"aaaxbbb"`にしたいです。

```
$data = Get-Content .\test.csv | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "",""}
```

`-replace`以降の指定の仕方がわかりません。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2702/3068)に陥っている可能性があるので確認なのですが、なぜカンマを別の文字に置き換えたいのでしょうか？その点を質問することでより良い回答が得られる可能性がありますので、その場合は **質問を編集** してみてください。

Comment: ちなみにRFC4180準拠のCSVを読み込みたいだけなら、 `Import-Csv -Header "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" .\test.csv` とすることで読み込めます。(CSVファイルの1行目がヘッダー行であれば `Import-Csv .\test.csv` だけでよいです)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。最終的にやりたいことはタブ区切りでsqlserverにbulkinsertしたいのです。普通であればダブルクォーテーションを削除してカンマをタブに変換すればいいのですが、ダブルクォーテーションの中にカンマが含まれているのがネックになっています。第1段階として、そのカンマを別の値（被らなければなんでもよい）に置換してからにしようと考えました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントでも触れられているように一旦`Import-Csv`で読みこんだ方が確実かと思います。
その後に生成された各オブジェクトのプロパティの値を加工して結合するだけです。

```
Import-Csv .\test.csv -Header (1..6) | foreach { $_.psobject.Properties.Value.Replace(",", "x") -join "`t" }
```

カンマのまま残すのであれば置換する必要もないので以下でいいです。

```
Import-Csv .\test.csv -Header (1..6) | foreach { $_.psobject.Properties.Value -join "`t" }
```

Comment: bulkinsertすることばかり考えていましたが、powershellからそのままインポートすることも考慮した方が良さそうですね。明日、会社で試してみます。

Answer (score 0):

SQL ServerにCSVファイルをインポートするのが目的なのですね。

もし、`SQL Server 2017`を利用しているのであれば、`BULK INSERT`の`FORMAT`オプションで`CSV`を指定すると、CSVファイルを取り込むことが可能です。

※対象ファイルが、harry0000さんのコメントにある、[RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)に準拠している必要があります。

参考:
[BULK INSERT (Transact-SQL) - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#input-file-format-options)

Comment: SQL Serverが2016なのでFOMATオプションが使えず、フォーマットファイルを作ろうかと思いましたが煩雑なのでpowershellでの処理を考えました。カンマは残したかったので2番目の方法で成型し、最終的に当初の予定通りbulk insertでうまくいきました。